# CodeIgniter: How to load css file that is WITHIN application folder

Tags: codeigniter, loading, external

It appears that this question is asked often and answered the same way: store the css files *outside* of the application directory and then use `base_url() . "path/to/file"`.

However, I want to keep my css files and js files *inside* my `application/views/` directory, because the `views` directory is effectively the html space, and css and js belong to that space (in my opinion).

Below is the structure that I wish for:

```
root
- application
-- views
--- assets
---- css
---- js
- system
```

When I attempt to load css files from within this directory structure, I get a `NetworkError: 403 Forbidden`, which makes sense because of CI's framework protocol.

But I am guessing that there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Publicly reachable files like CSSes images and JS files need to be in public directory next to index.php file. So hierarchy would be:

```
root
- application
- system
- assets
-- css
-- js
```

You can aproach to those files with hard coded

```
<a href="http://www.example.tld/assets/css/style.css">Link</a>
```

or using (loaded) url helper with it's function `base_url()` or `site_url()`. Don't forget to fill correct URL into application [config](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L6) file.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>">Link</a>
```

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html).

Comment: Tpojka, thanks for responding ... Why do they `need` to be? I realize that CI does not support this option out of the box, but that is why I posted my question ... thanks ...

Comment: Those directories (system, application) are not meant to be publicly reachable and `.htaccess` files in those are set to avoid public aproach for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i'm going to politely push back on this idea :-)
Your application and system folders should be ABOVE the root, so they are not publicly accessible. (Unless this is a really simple application and you are not doing any database interaction, etc). They should not be considered part of the HTML or public space because you do not want the public accessing them. Set the path for them once in the main index.php file and its done.

Also i suggest renaming your system and application folders, like "system302". Over the long term it makes versioning and upgrading (and reverting if needed) much easier.

Comment: Cartalot, thanks for responding ... I have not heard of moving `application` and `system` folders ABOVE the root ... however that is a different issue than what I am asking about ... my question accepts that those two directories are left as-is (ie below the root), and instead asks: can I put assets (such as css) somewhere within the `application` directory and access them from a view? ... thanks ...